# MongoDB not saving correct data and duplication records instead

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an express app.

In app.js I require mongoose and connect to my db.

**Here is the code for that which is in my app.js:**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect(CONNECTION STRING IS IN HERE);
```

In ./schemas I have a timelineItems.js which module.exports my model.

**Here is that model:**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var timelineItemsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    postedTime: String,
    postedPlace: String,
    postedContent: String,
    postedTitle: String,
});

var timelineItems = mongoose.model('timelime_items', timelineItemsSchema);

module.exports = timelineItems;
```

In admin-panel I require that schema and assign it to the variable `timelineItems`, I then say that `timelineItem` is a new version of that and pass in the req.body (to capture the data posted to the create route), here is that code:

```
router.post('/:action', function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.cookies.loggedIn) {
        if (req.params.action.toLowerCase() == "create") {

            var timelineItems = require("../schemas/timelineItems.js");

            console.log(req.body)

            var timelineItem = new timelineItems(req.body);

            console.log(timelineItem)

            timelineItem.save(function (err, item) {
                if (err) return console.error(err);
                res.send("item saved!");
                console.log(item)
            });

        } else {
            res.send("invalid post request - wrong route selected.");
        }

    } else {
        var err = new Error('Access forbidden, please login!');
        err.status = 403;
        next(err);
    }
});
```

All is good. When I post to the /admin-panel/create route, I get 3 console.log results in my terminal, as follows:

**The posted data (req.body):**

[image]

**The timelineItem:**

[image]

**The returned item from the .save function:**

[image]

Now, this is all well and good, but 4 times I have tried sending data, 4 times the terminal has shown the data as I would expect but when I go to the mlab mongoDB and look at the collection, It is saving random code with a different ID from the one I see in the terminal and also, it doesnt even save the data!!

I am so confused, how can the terminal tell me one thing but the database show another?

Here is a screenshot of the last 4 db entries with their ID's to show you that the data I sent is not among them, nor is the ID that is shown to me, the one in the DB, infact, none of the post requests I have sent and have had return showing as good in the console, actually saved correctly...

[image]

Am I doing something wrong here? I dont believe that I am, so why is it not saving the correct data and instead duplicating the last record already in the collection and just incrementing the id?

I am seriously confused, any ideas?

Comment: Can you find the `_id` from the item POSTed in your terminal anywhere in the `collection` on `mlab`? There is no guarantee of order in a MongoDB `collection`.

Comment: nope, not there at all

Comment: Is a new document being added every time? Or just no further documents are being added?

Comment: a new document is being added each time but not the same one as is showing in the terminal

Comment: I solved the issue, not sure how really, I merely altered the schema to add new fields I planed to implement... I am quite new to mongoose and mongo, I just dont get some things :P...

Comment: Could have been the extra `,` on the `postedTitle` Schema field. There should not be a comma there. Perhaps you have fixed it now?

Comment: Yeah, seems to be working as I would expect now, athough I am pretty sure that my code is quite inneficient